# CakePHP: is it possible to use model data in layouts?

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to display a ticker on each page what scrolls some of the latest datas in it. I think to put in the layout file would be more simply if I can read the model data from the layout.

Is it possible?

Or does layout code has access to the variables generated by a controller and passed to a view?
Or is it the only way to make an element and place it inside each view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty hard to understand what you're asking but i think it's something along the lines of

"How do I make a variable or dataset available to all views globally in CakePHP"

If so it's probabaly worth looking at the app_controller.php file ([book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller)) and the method `startUp()` you could run a query and assign it using `$this->set('ticker', $sql_result);`

Comment: That sounds greet I suppose that is what I am looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need is an [element](http://book.cakephp.org/view/97/Elements).

Answer (score 1):

And to answer the question : Yes, layout files have access to the variables set to the view in the controller, just like the views and the elements does.